# Is this formula regarding the domain of $ g\circ h$ correct? How to explain the presence of $h^{-1}$ in the formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, definition

I've recently encountered  on MSE the claim as to :

> $\operatorname{dom}(g \circ h) = \operatorname{dom}(h) \cap h^{-1}(\operatorname{dom}h)$.

If I am correct, this reads, in words as :

> the domain of the function composition  $g \circ h$ is the
>   intersection of the domain of  $h$ and of the image of the
>   domain of $h$ under the inverse function of $h$.

Is this correct?

How to explain where the inverse function comes from?

Comment: Something amiss here. For a start, what if $h$ has no inverse? [And NB: the notation $h^{-1}$ is standardly overloaded, so the notation $h^{-1}(A)$ doesn't presuppose that $h$ has an inverse].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$h$ needn't have an inverse. The notation $h^{-1}(A)$ means the set of all $x \in \textrm{dom}(h)$ such that $h(x) \in A$. Because $h^{-1}(A) \subseteq \textrm{dom}(h)$, we can say that $\textrm{dom}(g \circ h) = h^{-1}(\textrm{dom}(g))$. In other words, in order for $g(h(x))$ to be defined, $x$ must be in the domain of $h$, and $h(x)$ must be in the domain of $g$.